# Java inheritance with Redis

Tags: java, oop, jedis

Having subscriber class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import redis.clients.jedis.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Subscriber extends JedisPubSub {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Subscriber.class);


    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        logger.info("Message received. Channel: " + channel + ", Msg: " + message);

    }


    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
        logger.info("Subscribed to channel: " + channel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(masterName, sentinelsHashSet, password);
                    Jedis jPublisher = pool.getResource();
                    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
                    Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
                    jedis.subscribe(subscriber, channel);
                    jedis.quit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.run();
    }
}
```

Which basically print all messages received on Redis channel I wanted to create child class with different onMessage or onSubscribe methods. Im calling Subscriber class from Main class by

```
Subscriber sb = new Subscriber();
sb.main(new String[]{});
```

So I have tried:

1. Copy main method and change `Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();` to `SubscriberExtended subscriber = new SubscriberExtended();` and call from `Main` class by:
   1.1)

```
Subscriber sb = new SubscriberExtended();
sb.main(new String[]{});
```

or

```
SubscriberExtended sb = new SubscriberExtended();
sb.main(new String[]{});
```

```
    import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
    import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
    import redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class SubscriberExtended extends Subscriber {
        private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SubscriberExtended.class);

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
            logger.info("Subscribed to channel from Extended class: " + channel);
        }

        public SubscriberExtended() {

        }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(masterName, sentinelsHashSet, password);
                    Jedis jPublisher = pool.getResource();
                    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
                    SubscriberExtended subscriber = new SubscriberExtended();
                    jedis.subscribe(subscriber, channel);
                    jedis.quit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.run();

    }
```

2. Also I have tried to put in constructor

```
public SubscriberExtended() {
    super.main(new String[]{});
}
```

And few others configuration of those and nothing seems to be working.
What I'm trying to achieve is to create SubscriberExtended class which will behave same as Subscriber class but override onMessage or onSubscribe methods. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This appears that it should work, although I am not sure why you are adding a static main to all the classes.
You should be able to do the following:

```
public class Subscriber extends JedisPubSub {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Subscriber.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        logger.info("Message received. Channel: "+channel+", Msg: "+message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
        logger.info("Subscribed to channel: " + channel);
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(masterName, sentinelsHashSet, password);
                    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
                    jedis.subscribe(this, channel);
                    jedis.quit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}

public class SubscriberExtended extends Subscriber {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        logger.info("Extended Message received. Channel: "+channel+", Msg: "+message);
    }
}
```

Then, from your main function somewhere, you would have the following:

```
public class Main()
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SubscriberExtended se = new SubscriberExtended();
        se.start();

        while(true) {
             // do something else or sleep
        }
    }
}
```

I believe one mistake you made was to call t.run() instead of t.start().  t.run() will not return, unless the subscribe fails for some reason such as the connection to REDIS was closed. t.start() will kick off the thread.

You also seemed to grab a publisher connection from the jedis pool for no reason.

Another problem is here:

```
Subscriber sb = new SubscriberExtended();
sb.main(new String[]{});
```

`sb.main` will proceed to also call `new SubscriberExtended()` to use with the subscribe, and so your `sb` object will not receive any publications - they will go to the instance created inside sb.main instead.  Using 'this' inside the `start()` method to subscribe will address that issue.

Once that is set up, you can go ahead and connect to REDIS with redis-cli and issue a publish to see if your program receives the message.

Comment: One more thing you might change... you are creating a pool for each thread, and then using a single connection from the pool indefinitely.  You might want to just create a direct connection rather than a pooled connection.